# Jobs not chaining using JobChainingJobListener

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have the current code for my Quartz scheduler:

```
var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

// Job1
var Job1 = JobBuilder.Create<Test1>().WithIdentity("job1", "group1").Build();
// Job2
var Job2 = JobBuilder.Create<Test2>().WithIdentity("job2", "group2").Build();

// Triggers
ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1").StartNow().Build()
ITrigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("trigger2", "group2").StartNow().WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(1).WithRepeatCount(4)).Build();

// JobKeys
JobKey jobKey1 = new JobKey("Job1", "group1");
JobKey jobKey2 = new JobKey("Job2", "group2");

// Chain jobs
JobChainingJobListener chain = new JobChainingJobListener("testChain");
chain.AddJobChainLink(jobKey1, jobKey2);
scheduler.ScheduleJob(Job1, trigger1);
scheduler.AddJob(Job2, true);

// Global listener here. I am not sure what I have is correct.
scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(chain, GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup());` 

scheduler.Start();
```

(For clarification, the jobs do nothing more than print to console at the moment.)

From the Quartz website, I found that this will add a JobListener that is interested in all jobs: `scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(chain, GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup());` I'm not sure that this is equivalent to a global listener.

I also found that some code where people have done `scheduler.addGlobalJobListener(chain);` in Java. Is there an equivalent method in c#?

My code compiles and seems to run without errors, but Job2 does not trigger. Job1 prints properly to console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is that you have misspelled the key the second time ("Job1" vs "job1") which causes there to be no known link to fire. Here's updated code sample with redundancies removed.

```
var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
JobKey jobKey1 = new JobKey("job1", "group1");
JobKey jobKey2 = new JobKey("job2", "group2");

var job1 = JobBuilder.Create<Test1>().WithIdentity(jobKey1).Build();
var job2 = JobBuilder.Create<Test2>().WithIdentity(jobKey2).StoreDurably(true).Build();

ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
   .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
   .StartNow()
   .Build();

JobChainingJobListener chain = new JobChainingJobListener("testChain");
chain.AddJobChainLink(jobKey1, jobKey2);
scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(chain, GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup());

scheduler.ScheduleJob(job1, trigger1);
scheduler.AddJob(job2, true);

scheduler.Start();
```

The `scheduler.addGlobalJobListener` is old API and longer part of 2.x series. You should use the ListenerManager like you have done.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood whether it should have been the name of the job ("job1") or the Job variable name ("Job1"). Thank you for helping with that clarification.

Comment: I have another quick followup question. It seems that if I chain jobs, the second job will trigger after the competion of each instance of the first job. For example, if I have Job1's trigger be every minute for 5 minutes, Job2 will also occur every minute for 5 minutes. Is there a way to make it so Job2 triggers only once--after 5 minutes are up?

Comment: I guess then you need some custom logic. You can trigger another job using job execution context. Just check your own preconditions whether it should be done.