# How to delete a job and trigger/replace with a new job?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have a job that will continuously access a database and count the number of rows in a table. When the number reaches a certain threshold, the job must stop checking the table and trigger some new jobs. Right now, I'm trying to use `InterruptableJob` to do this, but I'm not sure how to delete the first job. That is:

(1) Job1 is triggered every 10 seconds. Accesses the SQL database and counts how many rows are in a given table.

(2) When there are 5 rows, Job1 will `Interrupt()`.

(3) Now Job2 needs to start, and Job1 must stop running. How do I delete Job1? I know `scheduler.DeleteJob()`, but I'm not sure when or where to call it, since I can't change `scheduler` within the class for `Job1`.

Also, how do I trigger Job2 to start running at this point? I have read about `JobChainingJobListener`, but as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515470/jobs-not-chaining-using-jobchainingjoblistener), I am also having problems getting the chained jobs to start.

For clarification, at the moment, Job2 does nothing more than print to console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now Job2 needs to start, and Job1 must stop running. How do I delete
>   Job1? I know scheduler.DeleteJob(), but I'm not sure when or where to
>   call it, since I can't change scheduler within the class for Job1

That last sentence is actually not correct. From the `IJobExecutionContext` passed to your job, you can easily access the scheduler and then remove the current job from the scheduler and schedule another one if needed.

Comment: Oh wow. I see how to access the scheduler from that now, thank you so much.