# how to queue jobs in quartz

Tags: quartz.net, job-scheduling

I have several quartz scheduled jobs. With the help of attribute  DisallowConcurrentExecution they do not execute simultaneously. But if they fire at one time, one job is missed. How to fix it (to put in queue)? I tried to use Mutex, but in result jobs were started and executed simultaneously, interrupting each other. I want one is done, the second will start after/ What to do?

Comment: I found the code example of using JobChainingJobListener here:
[Link to Stackoverflow post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515470/jobs-not-chaining-using-jobchainingjoblistener

Comment: I think you can use **lock** for your job method is when triggered, its gonna help for working sequentially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a  [JobChainingJobListener](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/?topic=html/b967d3fe-8333-abdc-baec-4e7c805a0af2.htm) for this. It listens for your job to finish and then triggers the next job on the list and so on.

Take a look at [the code](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Listener/JobChainingJobListener.cs) to see how it works if you want to do this on your own.

Comment: Thank you for advice. If i write this in listener - chainLinks.Add(firstJob, secondJob, thirdJob); - will it be executed as 1st, then 2nd, 3rd or to execute both or one of next job is up to schedule? For example if after 1st should fire only 3rd by schedule will it work?

Comment: The chaining listener will execute the second job after the first one completes, regardless of the second job's schedule. They're independent.

Comment: What if you have one separate main project where Quartz is not added because its the main app and you want to tell the separate Quartz project to enqueue a job? Can you reference somehow, or you need to add in database and poll from there.