# c# quartz.net schedule jobs to run in a queue

Tags: c#, triggers, queue, quartz.net, schedule

I have a small background process that serves message sending service built upon [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) lib.

The basic problem is that job trigger instruction `.StartNow()` starts concurently with the same instances of the current `MessageJob`.

And I've got no idea how to queue jobs of the same GROUP_NAME to run in FIFO queue one by one.

Here is a tiny sample:

```
using System;
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;

namespace Messaging
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var id = Guid.NewGuid();
                var job = JobBuilder.Create<MessageJob>()
                        .WithIdentity($"job_{id}", "MESSAGING")
                        .UsingJobData("Text", $"message_{i:D3}")
                        .Build();

                var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity($"trigger_{id}", "MESSAGING")
                    .StartNow()
                    .Build();

                scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MessageJob : IJob
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            var key = context.JobDetail.Key;
            Console.WriteLine($"job \'{key}\'. Text: {Text}");
        }
    }
}
```

This code causes race condition between same jobs of a single type. 
I would like to achieve next job fire triggering only if previous instance of `MessageJob` was succesfully executed, in order of `scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);` adding.

Comment: have you look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515470/jobs-not-chaining-using-jobchainingjoblistener ?

Comment: Yes, I have. That post guided me to create my own `JobListenerSupport` class that contains `ConcurrentQueue<JobKey>`. For some reason I can't post implementation right now, here, answering my own question.